# Where do I insert the ORDER BY in my MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to have my results sorted by "ORDER BY prod_name" in my SQL statement but I cannot figure out get it to work. I tried after

```
$thisProduct .= " AND prod_type = 1 ORDER BY prod_name";
```

and also after

```
$thisProduct .= " AND ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product']) . "' ORDER BY prod_name";
```

But I cannot get my results to sort correctly. Am I placing the order by in the wrong spot or did I query the DB incorrectly?

Thank you in Advance, I am still pretty new at MYSQL queries.

```
$thisProduct = "SELECT prod_name AS Name, days_span, CONCAT(LEFT(prodID,2),ID) AS ID,     geo_targeting FROM products WHERE status = 'Active' AND vendID = ".$resort['vendID'];
if (isset($_GET['product']) AND is_numeric($_GET['product'])) {
$thisProduct .= " AND ID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['product']) . "'";
}
else {
    $thisProduct .= " AND prod_type = 1";
}
$thisProduct .= " LIMIT 1";

$getThisProduct = mysql_query($thisProduct);
if (!$getThisProduct/*  OR mysql_num_rows($getThisProduct) == 0 */) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    require APP_PATH . '/404.html';
    die();
}

$thisProductData = mysql_fetch_assoc($getThisProduct);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have:

$thisProduct .= " ORDER BY  prod_name";
$thisProduct .= " LIMIT 1";

(Note that the LIMIT 1 means you only get one record).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your query is correct and you want the first product by name:

```
$thisProduct .= " ORDER BY prod_name LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should go right before your "LIMIT 1", as in:

```
$thisProduct .= " ORDER BY prod_name LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert it before the LIMIT

```
$thisProduct .= " ORDER BY prod_name LIMIT 1";
```

You can the select syntax at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0):

SELECT query usually takes following form

```
SELECT which_all_to_select 
FROM which_table/tables 
WHERE criteria 
ORDER BY column_name ASC/DESC;
```

`ASC` ascending order, and `DESC` is descending order

This orders query results by `column_name` specified in `ORDER BY` clause .