# MySQL WHERE ORDER BY on INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I looked through the documentation and I didn't seem to find anything describing how to do what I'm attempting.  Then again, I didn't find anything saying you couldn't either.

```
$querytotal = "insert into offer_det where where fname = '".$fname."' and lname = '".$lname."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`)
values($t1, $t2, $t3, $t4)";
$resultotal = mysql_query($querytotal);
```

My question: Is this an appropriate INSERT statement to make?  Essentially I'm just needing to match the first and last name, and then pick the most recent table entry for them, since there could be multiple table entries with the same first and last name.  From there all I need to do is insert the four values t1-4 with my variables $t1-4.

I saw this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747973/where-do-i-insert-the-order-by-in-my-mysql-query) but it didn't make a whole lot of sense.

Thanks for bearing with me on this one.

Comment: You are trying to do an insert based on a select from another table? That is possible.

Comment: Cue the furore over the mysql extension

Comment: I think you have one too many wheres ...

Comment: haha jesus, how did I miss the duplicated where

Comment: @user1718270 http://sqlfiddle.com is a great resource for testing your sql before you put it into a script.

Comment: @Asad, thanks for the resource.  I have been using the phpMyAdmin SQL query box for most things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sql is incorrect. Try this.

RE-RE EDITED:

```
$querytotal = "insert into offer_det (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`) values(’$t1’, ’$t2’, ’$t3’, ’$t4’) where  id = (SELECT max(id) FROM offer_det where fname = '".$fname."' and lname = '".$lname."')"; 
$resultotal = mysql_query($querytotal);
```

But are you sure you need an insert and not an update query?

Comment: This will insert the values into all the entries for fname and lname, but I only need it to insert on the most recent entry for that combination.  That is why I have the order by id.

Comment: Sorry. I didnt realize that. I have modified the query. That should work

Comment: I am not sure about that. But when you use max it does not query the whole table, but queries only one record. And also i am not querying all the columns. One row,one column. So it shouldnt make any difference.

Comment: Your max(id) subquery isn't going to work unless the very last inserted record was for the person who matches on fname and lname.

Comment: Yes. Agree. I have re-edited the query. Order by should be a better option then.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, my query: insert into offer_det (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`) values(1, 2, 3, 4) where `fname` = "Firstnamehere" and `lname` = "Lastnamehere" and `id` = (SELECT max(id) FROM offer_det ) turns out to error.  I'm not entirely sure the syntax is correct

Comment: Now you don't need the first fname/lname filters, you only need it in the id subquery.

Comment: Ya I dropped the fname and lname filters: insert into offer_det (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`) values($t1, $t2, $t3, $t4) where `id` = (SELECT max(id) FROM offer_det where fname = 'Bob' and lname = 'Smith') -- it definitely is not liking that where id = select statement

Comment: The values don't have quotes. Please surround them with quotes.

Comment: Even with quotes, it doesn't like it

Comment: I've changed my process to two separate queries: $query11 = "select `id` from offer_det where fname = '".$fname."' and lname = '".$lname."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result11 = mysql_query($query11);
$curid = $result11;
$querytotal = "insert into offer_det(`t1`, `t2`, `t3`, `t4`) values($t1, $t2, $t3, $t4) where `id` = '".$curid."'"; 
$resultotal = mysql_query($querytotal);

not that it returns results

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this...

```
$querytotal = "insert into offer_det (t1, t2, t3, t4) " .
"select t1, t2, t3, t4 from offer_det where fname = '$fname' and lname = '$lname' order by id desc limit 1";
$resultotal = mysql_query($querytotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you want but, maybe you need something like this

```
    $query = "Insert into offer_det (t1, t2, t3, t4)
               (SELECT $t1, $t2, $t3, $t4 FROM offer_det where
              fname = '".$fname."' and lname = '".$lname."' ORDER BY ID DESC Limit 1)";
```

This will insert (t1, t2, t3, t4) in this table, based on last result with fname and lnam from same table.